# TargetParameterCountException when iteratively retrieving value out of reflexive properties of a string

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-4.5

Some context first :

I was writing a reusable "null tester" method that will be used to check if any variable of an object has a null or empty value. the goal is that the method can take an `Object` and use reflexion to check the value of each property.

Everything worked until I added a `List<string>` to a class that is being checked. 
While adding `List<string>` raised the TargetParameterCountException other primitive types didn't. The only other time I managed to reproduce this error is when I passed directly a string.

I managed to boil down this problem to that bit of code :

```
string toCheck = "foo";
var elementProperties = toCheck.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in elementProperties)
{
    var elementValue = property.GetValue(toCheck);
    //Check if "toCheck" is null or empty here
}
```

`elementProperties` has two Values

- An `Int32 Length`
- A `Char Chars[Int32]`

My understanding would be that the first represent the length and the second the content of the string. But when the code tries to "`GetValue()`" the second property it raises a `TargetParameterCountException`.

Does someone know why it would do that ?

Comment: You posted it by yourself: `Char Chars[Int32]`. This property takes an Int32 as first parameter. You did not provide one, thats your exception.

Comment: Yes, this worked thanks, i needed to use the second parameter of getValue to access the specific index of the char array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since I was trying to access a char array I needed to specify the index of which char I want to retrieve.
using :

```
property.GetValue(toCheck, new object[] {index})
```